# Calculations inside loop with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've this data set:

```
data = {
    'index': [4, 17, 24, 36, 42],
    'High': [805.000000, 1094.939941, 1243.489990, 1201.949951, 1172.839966],
}
```

And I would like to get a slope, like:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(data)

for i in range(len(test)):
    test.loc[:,'slope'] = (test.loc[i+1,'High'] - test.loc[i,'High'])   / (test.loc[i+1,'index'] - test.loc[i,'index'])

print(test)
```

Seems that I'm going out of the boundaries of the loop, but how can I code this in order to get the first row blank and fill the next?

If I do the same code without the +1 and use i instead it works, gives a 0/0 (Nan), but works.

The expected output should be:

[image: expected output]

Comment: Well, looping row by row in pandas is not the fastest way to solve it, but can you see why `i+1` goes out of bounds in the last iteration?  Any thoughts on how you'd solve that?

Comment: Looping through a DataFrame should be your last option, you should avoid it at all costs because it's very slow, especially if you are working with a large dataset. As @creanion suggested, just use  `test['slope'] = test['High'].diff() / test['index'].diff()`. It's a vectorized and cleaner solution.   
`

Answer (score 4):

A whole-column way to compute this is like this:

We can use `diff` to make a series of differences vs the previous value:

```
test['index'].diff()
```

```
0     NaN
1    13.0
2     7.0
3    12.0
4     6.0
Name: index, dtype: float64
```

Using that we can compute the High difference over the index difference per step:

```
test['High'].diff() / test['index'].diff()
```

```
0          NaN
1    22.303072
2    21.221436
3    -3.461670
4    -4.851664
dtype: float64
```

It's an arbitrary choice IMO about where the index alignment should be - should this sequence start at index 0 or 1? But what you expect in the question is that it starts with 1, like in the result here.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution!  The problem I see in your solution is how to do diff when I don't want to do it between non consecutive rows.

Comment: Consecutive rows is what you do in your question, so that's all I know and can know about :)  So what's your new question?

Answer (score 3):

Just subtract the 1 from the range, so for loop will not go out of the boundaries

```
for i in range(len(test)-1):
    test.loc[i+1,'slope'] = round((test.loc[i+1,'High'] - test.loc[i,'High'])   / (test.loc[i+1,'index'] - test.loc[i,'index']),2)
```

Better solution would be using Shift function , as for loop will take longer time
for the large dataset -

```
test['slope'] = round((test['High']-test['High'].shift(1)) / (test['index']-test['index'].shift(1)),2)
test
```

Comment: I've finally used the shift option adding more decimals to the round to get more precision, is exactly what I needed.  THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 2):

Just give it a condition, if index is zero then skip it and change the calculation a bit. Also i spot some human error, u type `test.loc[:,'slope']` instead `test.loc[i,'slope']`

```py
for i in range(len(test)):
    test.loc[i,'slope'] = 0 if i==0 else (test.loc[i,'High'] - test.loc[i-1,'High'])   / (test.loc[i,'index'] - test.loc[i-1,'index'])
```